# Time Based Profiling with perf record

Tags: performancecounter, perf

Would you inform me how can I get the value of event counters at each sample when using perf record?

For example:

`perf record -F 100 -e instructions ./program`

With perf report, I only see overhead. But I want to know if there are ways to view the value of the counter at each sample...

Comment: Check also `perf stat` with `-I` mode of time-periodic sampling; for time based sampling with record use `-e cpu-clock` event and `-c` for exact event count (-F will do autotuning between sampling interrupts to keep sample rate around your request). Perf script just parses what is recorded in the perf.data, it just shows event samples and the timestamp for every sample.

Comment: @osgx Thanks. I actually have tried using perf stat with -I command but because the execution time of workloads is so short under 10ms and the minimum time that perf stat -I allows is 10 ms this command was not so useful to me. So, I have used perf script and filtered the samples of workloads of my interest along with their time stamp an event count...
Thanks for your comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question in case someone else is facing the same issue.

In order to view the time at which sample is taken and the value of the counter at that time, you can use `perf script` after executing `perf record`.